# Gooddata Javascript API - Attribute not supported

Tags: javascript, gooddata

Adjusting the d3-data-viz example code to fit a project and when the values of the below lines are changed to identifiers from the project, the code returns a 400 (Bad Request)

```
{
"error":
  {
    "errorClass":"com.gooddata.webapp.service.simpleexecutor.UnsupportedTypeException",
    "trace":"",
    "message":"Type attribute not supported in simple execution.",
    "component":"Webapp",
    "errorId":"51ab443c-b4a3-47be-a434-2cecfc4f244f",
    "errorCode":"gdc.webapp.execution.unsupported_type",
    "parameters":["attribute"]
  }
}
```

Code from example viz.js:

```
var metric = 'afSEwRwdbMeQ',
    attr1 = 'oppclose.aam81lMifn6q',
    attr2 = 'label.opp_owner.id.name';
var elements = [attr1, attr2, metric];
```

Comment: Have you changed anything in the example? The part where you define elements looks same and it is working for me...

Answer (score 2):

For the execution API used for d3-data-viz example you have to provide identifiers of either **attribute labels** or **metrics**, not **attributes**. Thats what the error says.

In your example, I can see that `attr2` is attribute label from its identifier (because it starts with `label`). So the element causing the error is either `attr1` or `metric`.

How to get attribute label identifier is described in following developer article

https://developer.gooddata.com/article/acquiring-object-identifiers-for-project-metadata#AcquiringSpecialLDMIdentifiers

Comment: Weird is that this example runs against demo Project and so identifiers should be the same...I have same identifiers and works for me.

Comment: @JiriTobolka You are right, if I try calling the execution API using demo project with the identifiers Tom posted, I get result successfully. The error message is clear though. Maybe Tom used different project?